# Discord.py how can bot mention a channel by id

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that is getting id and mention channel by id. This command is just the test side. I have channels id in a text file. Then i will get channels id from text file then mention channels. But i tried to a test command and it didn't work. How can i do this job with ctx module? I don't have channel names, just using channels id.

here is my code:

```
@Bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.channel.send(ctx.channel(id=817xxxx16575xxx895).mention)
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to mention your context channel:

```py
await ctx.send(ctx.channel.mention)
```

If you're trying to mention just one channel that you'll hard-code the id for:

```py
await ctx.send(Bot.get_channel(id).mention)
```

Though a couple notes about that and your code, id is an arg, not a kwarg, so just pass the integer, not id=

If you want to mention a channel where the id is given in the message:

```py
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(Bot.get_channel(int(arg)).mention)
```

though i would advise using a try...except block for that in case its not a valid channel id

Comment: You can also use the raw mention string: `<#{channel_id}>`

Comment: `await ctx.send(Bot.get_channel(id).mention)` is not working. I puted the id on id side but it's giving this errror **ctx.channel.send(Bot.get_channel(817xxxx16575xxx895).mention)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback**

Comment: @Conqueror you can't have Xs in your id, where did you get it from? The proper way is by enabling developer mode then using "copy id" from various things to get it

Comment: In the code you're using `ctx.send`, however the error is mentioning `ctx.channel.send` @Conqueror...

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński ctx.channel.send actually works fine, it's just exactly the same as ctx.send, so it's easier to ignore channel

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński OHH okay, sorry, I see

Comment: @Alyx the code OP provided is `await ctx.send(Bot.get_channel(id).mention)`, however the error is: `ctx.channel.send(Bot.get_channel(817xxxx16575xxx895).mention) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`, he's not posting the correct code snippet

Comment: @Conqueror The one other thing i noticed that could potentially be an issue is upper case Bot, you might be overriding an existing value in discord.py or something, if you change "Bot" to "bot" everywhere and try again, I think it may work

Comment: Sorry my fault. i copied wrong code. i tried "ctx.send" and "ctx.channel.send" but it is still not working

Comment: @Alyx but client name is "Bot" not "bot". if i try to "bot" I'm getting this error "bot not defined"

Comment: Can you show some more code? It's kind of hard for me to help with code I cant see, just like, your class and bot declaration would help a lot

Comment: here is my import side:
`import os
import sys
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from discord.ext.commands import Bot, has_permissions, CheckFailure

from discord.utils import get
import emoji

my_secret = os.environ['locksecret']

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True,guilds=True,reactions=True,members=True,presences=True)

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!",intents=intents)`

Comment: Ah, i think i may see some of the issue, first, you dont need to import Bot manually, since you're still calling on it via commands.Bot, and second, I think that may actually be your main issue there with the capitalization, since now you have the object Bot in commands.Bot being overriden by your code, try deleting the import Bot part and see if that helps

Comment: thank you for advice. i deleted the "Bot" from import side. but it's still not working.
`intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True,guilds=True,reactions=True,members=True,presences=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!",intents=intents)
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  ctx.send(bot.get_channel(817538816575012895).mention)`
error:
**main.py:21: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
  ctx.send(bot.get_channel(817538816575012895).mention)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback**

Comment: oh, you need to just add "await " before ctx.send!

Comment: oh sorry. thx problem fixed. i think i have to read more discord.py docs :) thank you a lot

Comment: No problem!! Would you mind marking my answer as accepted? (You dont need to, but it indicates your question has been resolved and helps me out!)